# PHP Variable Variables and Array Index

Tags: php

I think this can be a simple problem for some of you. I've discovered similar questions, but they don't exactly solve my problem.

I've two arrays.

$array_numerals

```
Array
(
[2] => two
[3] => three
[4] => four
[5] => five
[6] => six
[7] => seven
)
```

$array_two

```
Array
(
[0] => $100
[1] => $200
[2] => $300
)
```

If I use

```
echo $array_two[0];
```

it shows the output properly, which is `$100`, as expected.

what I want to do is to make the "two" and the "[0]" dynamic. the "two" can be replced with "three" or "four" while the "[0]" can be replaced with "[1]" or "[2]".

So if I use

```
$i = 2;
$j = 0;

echo $array_{$array_numerals[$i]}[$j];
```

it doesn't work and shows empty value.

Edit: Thank you all for the comments and answers. I must add that $array_two, $array_three, etc. are fixed variables given by another source, so it's not like I can control the initial construction of these arrays. Hence, the answers given by some of you won't work out of the box (not your fault of course, perhaps I didn't clarify enough in the beginning). The answers given by Amadan and LuvnJesus work the best.

Comment: can you please add expected out for your question?

Comment: What you're trying to do there is impossible the way you are doing it. Instead, you need to use a jagged array, which is an array of arrays.

Comment: @amit-shah the expected output for the second code block should be the same as the first code block, which is "$100".

Comment: You can do this using $$var in PHP.  Lets you store a variable or array name in a variable.  I've used it rarely but it does work.  Example shown in answer post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo ${"array_$array_numerals[$i]"}[$j];
```

But I must warn you that it is a very bad idea to do this.
Rather, use another lookup array:

```
$array = Array(
  0 => Array(
    2 => "$100",
    ...
  ),
  ...
);

echo $array[$i][$j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
$array['two'][0]
$array['three'][0]
$array['four'][0]
$array['four'][1]
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use it like this:

```
$array_two[0] = $array_two[1];
```

And do the same thing with the other array.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the "name" of the array and store it in a variable:

```
$arrayname = "array_".$array_numerals[$i];
```

Store the array values into a new array

```
$newarray = $$arrayname;
```

Now output whichever elements you wish:

```
echo $newarray[$j];
```

Altogether you have:

```
$arrayname = "array_".$array_numerals[$i];
$newarray = $$arrayname;
echo $newarray[$j];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `compact` function. I have used your array and created result as you need. please [check here](https://3v4l.org/iHEbf)